# thunderbolt port not sending video

Tags: usb, display, hdmi

I have a razr stealth RZ0901952E72 running ubuntu20.04 5.4.0-58-generic.
When using a macbook with usb-c ports I could run a philips 243V5L using a usbc-hdmi cable.
I'd like to do the same with the stealth (which has a usb-c style port that is apparently a 'thunderbolt 3' and an hdmi port which works fine, the point of this whole exercise being to run two or more external screens) but so far no dice.

xrandr with nothing connected (and also with thunderbolt connected to ext monitor thru usbc-hdmi cable) shows:

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
 ...
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

while with hdmi connected it shows:

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
...
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
...
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050 (0x1bf) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1c3) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x1c1) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1024x768 (0x1c6) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1c8) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x1cb) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

and again I get the same output when the thunderbolt port is also connected to ext monitor thru usbc-hdmi cable.  In other words connecting the usbc-hdmi to the thunderbolt port doesn't seem to change anything.

The thunderbolt does seem to be 'for real' (if you didn't trust the 'thunderbolt 3' of the [mfg tech spec](https://dl.razerzone.com/master-guides/RazerSynapse/Blade-00000548-en.pdf)

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/$ lsmod|grep thund
thunderbolt           167936  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi                    32768  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,mxm_wmi
```

For the sake of completeness I'll also throw in:

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO UART #0 (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01)
```

Update after further googling - maybe what I need is a usb-c to displayport like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071W3B69M) which would also get me some further monitors .

Answer (score 0):

> Update after further googling - maybe what I need is a usb-c to displayport like this which would also get me some further monitors .

That will not get video from the USB-C port on your computer because the computer does not support DP output from that port.  To add another display to your computer will require adding another GPU.  You point out that the computer already has a GPU but that GPU only supplies video to the internal display and the HDMI port, it has no DP output that you can reach.  It's possible that the GPU has a DP connection somewhere on the circuit board but that connection is not accessible without a screwdriver and soldering iron.  If you believe otherwise then you need to contact the manufacturer because it appears your DP output is broken and is in need of repair.  If the USB-C to HDMI cable you have works fine with a MacBook bu not your razer computer then the problem lies with the computer.  It either does not support DP output on its USB-C port or the port is in need of repair.

Comment: An update after happening across new information... It's possible the DP output of the USB-C port can be enabled/disabled in BIOS.  Some manufacturers will have an option for users that allow (or rather force) the user to choose between video output to USB-C or some other port such as a VGA or HDMI port.  Many GPUs will have only two video outputs, and with a laptop one of them will be to the internal display.  USB-C allows for auto-detection of a display connected to a port but for matters of cost or convenience a manufacturer my have this set by the user instead.  Check the manual for this.

Answer (score -1):

The MacBook supports both DP and TB3 on the USB-C ports which allows the use of a USB-C to HDMI cable to get video to the display.  I'm not seeing anything that indicates DP support from the USB-C port on the razer.  Since it has a port for HDMI 2.0 then use that to plug in your HDMI display.  My guess is that since this is a gaming laptop the TB3 port was intended for an external GPU, not to connect a DP display directly.  Other options would be to use as a fast network for team play, connection for VR/AR goggles, more storage, more processing that can include a GPU or CPU.  If the goal is just connecting the HDMI display then get a cable and be done.  If you are looking for some 8K high refresh magic then it is time for a GPU.

Comment: the laptop has a gpu (gtx 1060) as you can see from the lspci , and the 'DP-1 disconnected'  output from xrandr seems to hint that displayport is supported, no?

Comment: The other hdmi port is for another screen, the ultimate point here was to try for 2 (or more) external monitors.

Comment: The manufacturer spec sheet does not show that DP output is supported on the USB-C port.  Your experimentation shows there is no DP output on the USB-C port.  The presence of a GPU in the computer is not relevant to your problem.  The GPU reporting that the DP port is disconnected can merely mean the GPU supports DP but nothing was wired to it internally.  I believe you need to contact the manufacturer.  Either the port does not support DP output or it should but it's broken.

Comment: The point about the internal GPU was in response to your assumption that 'the TB3 port was intended for an external GPU'

Comment: " The point about the internal GPU was in response to your assumption that 'the TB3 port was intended for an external GPU' "  A gaming computer with a single GPU that is capable of supporting only two displays at 1080p will want to leave the option for adding a GPU capable of dual 4K displays, a 5K display, or whatever.  It appears quite logical for the USB-C port to lack DP-output as it is intended for an additional GPU, a fast network, VR/AR goggles, RAID or other storage, or whatever suits you.  I'm not seeing DP-out on that port and the only thing that will change that is another GPU.